# `dyld: Library not loaded` error when not using use_frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have a private pod called XXCommonUtils which has one dependency installed via Cocoapods, EDSunriseSet.

The podspec for my private pod looks like this

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name = "XXCommonUtils"
  s.module_name = 'XXCommonUtils'
  s.version = "2.0.2"
  s.summary = "XX CommonUtils Component"
  s.homepage = 'https://www.xx.com'
  s.license = { :type => "Private", :text => "Copyright 2016-2018 by XX. All right reserved." }
  s.author = { "XX XX" => "xx.xx@xx.com" }
  s.source = { :git => "https://github.xx.com/TSS-XX-CoreApp/iOS-Stage-Frameworks", :tag => "XXCommonUtils-2.0.2-Beta" }
  s.swift_version = '4.1.2'
  s.platform = :ios, '8.0'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'XXCommonUtils/XXCommonUtils.framework'
  s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'CoreData'
  s.dependency 'EDSunriseSet', '1.0'
end
```

You can see the EDSunriseSet dependency defined here.

I am importing this private Pod in to an application with the following Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.xx.com/TSS-XX-CoreApp/iOS-Stage-CocoaPods.git'


target 'netperf01' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    #  use_frameworks!

    pod 'XXCommonUtils', '2.0.2'

    # Pods for netperf01

    target 'netperf01Tests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
    end

end
```

I see that both the common utils private pod and it's dependency EDSunriseSet are installed in the pod install output.

When I run the application, I get an instant crash with this error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/EDSunriseSet.framework/EDSunriseSet

Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CF8F6C93-2BCF-44F5-B5D1-8B567777271A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9E462A24-0417-494F-9081-77D9A33C3B7D/netperf01.app/Frameworks/XXCommonUtils.framework/XXCommonUtils
  Reason: image not found
```

If I uncomment `#  use_frameworks!` in my application Podfile then the app works as normal, however unfortunately this is not a suitable fix for the client attempting the use the XXCommonUtils library. Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Is EDSunriseSet a swift pod?

Comment: No Obj-C https://github.com/erndev/EDSunriseSet

Comment: It looks like you're referring to the framework that you're building within the pod spec? I would guess that would be where the issue might be arising. If you're not building the XXCommonUtils as a framework, then what are you referencing in the `s.ios.vendored_frameworks` line?